# Как вызвать си-функцию qsort в ассемблере

Tags: c, функции, ассемблер

Если прототип функции такой:

```
void qsort ( void * first, size_t number, size_t size, int ( * comparator ) ( const void *, const void * ) );
```

То как её вызвать в ассемблере?
Я пробовал что-то такое

```
section .data
    a dd 1, 3, 2, 2
    c dd 10
    b dd 4
section .text
CMAIN:
...
    push dword[comp]
    push dword[b]
    push dword[c]
    push dword[a]
    call qsort;программа вылетает на этом месте, дальше не идет
    add esp, 16
    PRINT_DEC 4, [a + 4]
    xor eax, eax
    ret

comp:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov edx, dword[ebp + 4]
    mov eax, dword[ebp + 8]
    sub eax, edx
    leave
    ret
```

но в итоге ничего не работает

Comment: почему элементов в массиве 4, а вы передаете значение 10 ? Так же обратите внимание, что первый параметр это указатель, а следующие 2 - значения. однако все 3 параметра вы передаете одинаковым способом... А вообще запускайте под отладчиком и смотрите куда что заносите. отличайте значения от указателей (т.е. адресов, где находится переменная/функция)

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий пример: (POASM, MASM compatible)

```
.code
    public c main
    main:
        push comp
        push dword ptr [b]
        push dword ptr [c]
        push a
        call qsort
        add esp, 16
        push a
        push f
        call vprintf
        add esp, 8
        xor eax, eax
        ret
    comp:
        mov eax, dword ptr [esp+4]
        mov edx, dword ptr [esp+8]
        mov eax, dword ptr [eax]
        sub eax, dword ptr [edx]
        ret
.data
    public a
    a:  dd 1, 3, 2, 2
    c:  dd 4
    b:  dd 4
    f:  db "%i,%i,%i,%i",13,10,0
```

Comment: Только поправьте объявления секций под себя. Компиляторы разные немного.